# Достать определенную часть HTML-кода со страницы и записать в файл в Selenium + BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, selenium, beautiful-soup

Использую Selenium + BeautifulSoup, подскажите, пожалуйста, как достать определенную часть HTML-кода со страницы и записать в файл. Должен записаться кусочек HTML-кода с классом `heading__name`, но записывается код всей страницы.

```
html_content = driver.page_source.encode("utf-8").strip()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")
...
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[2])
requared_html = driver.page_source
name = driver.find_element("css selector", ".heading__name")
with open("home_team_injuries.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    file.write(requared_html)
```

Comment: чет то у вас намешано. BeautifulSoup который не принимает участие, нужно записать кусок HTML, а записывается весь HTML видимо еще и проблемы с кодировкой

Comment: Наверное надо file.write(name)

Comment: я так понимаю вам надо в файл записать "Райан Бертран (Травма колена)"?

Comment: @Сергей Ш, но записать не текст, а html-код

Comment: хоть адрес страницы напишите, хочу посмотреть в чем подвох.

Comment: @Сергей Ш, https://www.soccerstand.com/ru/player/castrovilli-gaetano/ALBpOZPH такой тип игроков

Comment: вам в файл нужно записвть <div class="heading__name">Гаэтано Кастровилли</div>? Если нет, то напишите что ожидаете получить в файле?

Comment: @Сергей Ш, да, но в итоге, я буду сохранять игрока с травмой. Так как через Selenium не добраться до травмы, там svg и я никак не могу это спарсить, поэтому буду сохранять кусочек кода в файл, а дальше уже с файла парсить через bs4. Мне же надо просто записать кусочек кода игрока, без травмы сейчас - просто чтоб я понял как это делается.